# How to import non-TypeScript assets from a TypeScript file using Parcel

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, parceljs

Here is an excerpt from the Parcel docs:

> You can also import non-JavaScript assets from a JavaScript file, e.g.
>   CSS, HTML or even an image file. When you import one of these files,
>   it is not inlined as in some other bundlers. Instead, it is placed in
>   a separate bundle (e.g. a CSS file) along with all of its
>   dependencies. When using CSS Modules, the exported classes are placed
>   in the JavaScript bundle. Other asset types export a URL to the output
>   file in the JavaScript bundle so you can reference them in your code.
>
> ```
> // Import a CSS file
> import './test.css'
>
> // Import a CSS file with CSS modules
> import classNames from './test.css'
>
> // Import the URL to an image file
> import imageURL from './test.png'
>
> // Import an HTML file
> import('./some.html')
> // or:
> import html from './some.html'
> // or:
> require('./some.html')
> ```
>
> If you want to inline a file into the JavaScript bundle instead of
>   reference it by URL, you can use the Node.js fs.readFileSync API to do
>   that. The URL must be statically analyzable, meaning it cannot have
>   any variables in it (other than __dirname and __filename).
>
> ```
> import fs from 'fs'
>
> // Read contents as a string
> const string = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/test.txt', 'utf8')
>
> // Read contents as a Buffer
> const buffer = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/test.png')
>
> // Convert Buffer contents to an image
> ;<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${buffer.toString('base64')}`} />
> ```

I've tried doing some of these but from a TypeScript file and it does not seem to work.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

component.html

```
<h1>Some really big text</h1>
<p>Some much smaller text</p>
```

component.css

```
h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

component.ts

```
import { styles } from './component.css;
import { html } from './component.html;

class Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
  super();

  // Append the styles and html to shadowRoot on element
}

customElements.define('app-root', Component);
```

The idea is to define custom-elements using their own separate html, css and ts files. Then the root index.html file can point to a main.ts file and main.ts can import all the components files. How can I make this work?

Comment: you are missing an apostrophe after ./component.css and ./component.html

Comment: And also, do it like this: 
    import * as styles from './component.css';